# Time saving or time savings?

Tags: grammaticality

This is for a questionnaire. There are multiple options to choose from that indicate that I can save time with a certain option. I am wondering whether to use "time savings" or "time saving" in this context:

> Routing A: Time saving of 30 minutes with a probability of 50 percent.

or

> Routing A: Time savings of 30 minutes with a probability of 50 percent.

Various translation sites give me the first option as correct, but this might be because they translate from German, where the first option is the literal translation. My gut says it is the second.

Comment: I think both sentences sound like awkward fragments without verbs. “Time” is unnecessary when “minutes” already indicates time. I’d expect something like, “Route A: Saves 30 minutes with a probability of 50%”. Alternatively, “Route A: Yields savings of 30 minutes...”.  Have you considered the idiomatic expression “travel time” too? As used here: https://www.parliament.nsw.gov.au/lcdocs/other/10700/Answers%20to%20supplementary%20questions%20-%20Transurban%20-%20Appendix%202.pdf

Comment: Notice that German forms compound words that work well as units but “time savings” is not as closely bound together as the equivalent German expression and so we are more inclined to split the words up etc. in different contexts.

Comment: The other obvious option that I missed was: “Route A: Saving 30 minutes with a probability of...”. I notice now that I unconsciously changed “routing” to “route”. Unless there is a particular context preventing it, I’d prefer the ordinary noun “Route” here.

Comment: One is single, one is plural, but something can offer a single time saving or multiple time savings depending on the specifics.

Comment: 'Savings' may correspond to a single amount of money in an account. The plural form is used even if I've only put one deposit into an account. I'd say neither is incorrect, in your example, but that the singular form (time saving; I'd use 'a time saving' here) is more idiomatic.

Comment: There is no need for the word saving. This saves 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't follow your gut as shown here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time-saving the correct way to say this sentence is "Time saving of 30 minutes with a probability of 50 percent.

Time saving is singular Time savings is plural in this case it's one time saving, so routing a is the correct answer.

Comment: You could consider a routing as offering multiple time savings, for instance if it saves some time at the start, and separately saves some time at the end, or if it includes multiple options or possibilities, or various other ways. There's no way of answering the question without guessing.

Comment: The dictionary definition is for the compound adjective, which is never spelled with a final _s_.